# How to avoid MissingMethodException?

Tags: .net

If .NET 3.5 is installed, but not .NET 3.5 SP1, `WaitHandle.WaitOne(int)` throws a `MissingMethodException`. I'd like to be notified earlier on if the correct version of the .NET libraries is not available, for example when the application is started. Is this possible?

**Update**: So my question question is twofold:

- **a)** How can I determine which version of the .NET library is required by an application?
- **b)** How can I determine the currently installed version of the .NET library?

Answer (score 1):

You can check Framework version in the registry, take a look:
[so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951856/is-there-an-easy-way-to-check-net-framework-verison-using-c)