# How to install the current version of .net at the start of my Desktop application?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a distributed WinForms application, at the start of client I would detect the current version in the computer and install upgrade if necessary.

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: As a prerequisite in the installer. Unless you decide on an installer technology, there's not much more that can be said about it.

Comment: @marc_s or [How To Check If The .Net Framework Is Installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945006/how-to-check-if-the-net-framework-is-installed-c-wpf) then, where the answer is _"You can not do this from your application. The application will fail to start"_. This question is not unique or specific enough to be answered, imho, but if you feel like it please feel free to reopen. OP: please add additional details about what exactly you want to check and install or update, and show what you have found.

Comment: @CodeCaster: agreed - the question is a bit misleading because the title talks about installing the .NET framework, while the body (at least to me) seems to talk about auto-updating ....

Comment: The Client are win7, all have the .net framework but many computer have the 3.5 or 4.0, at the start of application I would control the current version and install the upgrade to 4.5 if necessary.

The Client computers have the internet connection how prerequisite...Client Application WinForm use the distribuited WebServices for work