# Where does the .NET framework come from? Visual Studio or Windows?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I am learning C# and have installed Visual Studio 2012 on a PC running Windows 7.

I can now browse to the `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET` directory.

My first question is:

Does Visual Studio ship with the .NET directory, or does Visual Studio just access the directory that already exists on a computer running Windows 7?

My second related question is:

The highest numbered folder at the location `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\` is `v4.0.30319`.  This confuses me because the version number associated with Visual Studio 2012 in the table at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#History is `4.5.50709.17929`.

So why do I not have a folder with that higher version number if I installed Visual Studio a couple of weeks ago?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows 7 comes with .NET 3.5 SP1. Visual Studio does not ship with .NET.. however, .NET ships with Visual Studio (obviously, so you can develop on it).

The version number didn't change between 4 and 4.5 .. I cannot remember the reason why (I think it had something to do with it being an in-place upgrade.. or something). This is why the folder version numbering is the same.

EDIT:

You can look here for a better explanation of the .NET 4/4.5 versioning and what the exact revision numbers mean: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12972517/1517578

Comment: When you say '.NET ships with Visual Studio', do you mean Visual Studio is already installed in Windows 7 (as it comes with .NET)?  As it seems I can just download .NET here without Visual Studio:  http://www.microsoft.com/net/downloads ?

Comment: What I mean is, Visual Studio ships with the latest .NET version that was available at time of release. There are .NET releases in-between Visual Studio releases.. so that is why there are .NET downloads too. However, you cannot get Visual Studio just by installing .NET.

Answer (score 2):

Visual studio is just an IDE that requires the .NET framework. Lots of applications require the .NET framework so there's a chance that you could have had .NET installed before installing VS. Installing VS, however, will ensure you have the correct .NET runtime for your version.

.NET 4.5 is an in place replacement to the .NET 4.0 framework so the folder will still be called v4.0.... I guess this is a way to avoid problems with systems built on .NET 4.0

There is a good article [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NETVersioningAndMultiTargetingNET45IsAnInplaceUpgradeToNET40.aspx) about .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio ships with the .NET directory and it also accesses the directory if that already exists. One can install .Net 4.5 separately too

The highest numbered folder `v4.0.30319` is the version of the CLR and not the .Net Libraries. .Net v4.5 replaces v4.0 similar to the way v3.0, v3.5 and v3.5SP1 replace v2.0 still the CLR version remains v2.0.xxxxx. This is the reason why you don't have a folder with higher version number.

Answer (score 0):

It comes with `windows os`. If you go to ***Turn Windows features on or off*** you will see the Microsoft .NET framework