# Dot Net 4.0.30319 Initialization error

Tags: .net, windows

Running Windows 7.  Been getting the attached error for a few different programs recently.  More or less Windows doesn't detect my installed version of Dot Net.

Been googling all over the place, haven't found a solution that works. More or less, lots of uninstall/reinstalls are suggested which hasn't worked.

Any pointers?

[image: DotNet Not Detected]

Comment: Are you running 64 or 32-bit Windows?

Answer (score 3):

You may actually need to [install .NET 4.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653).  The version number for .NET 4 and 4.5 is the same (`4.0.30319`), as 4.5 is an in-place upgrade to 4.0.

The only [version difference is the build number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12972517/65358), which is not being reported in that dialog.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  No luck though, figured out I have this issue (mscoree.dll version 2, not updated by .Net 4).  Working through those steps now...  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsnetsetup/archive/2011/05/20/net-framework-initialization-error.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you may be having a registry issue.

If installing the newer version of 4.5 doesn't resolve your issue, you may need to look into uninstalling and re-installing your .NET application.

You can also detect if your Registry Keys are showing the correct version here :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568.aspx