# How to programmatically check the .NET Core Runtime version installed on my machine from a .NET Framework app?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, version

I am writing an application in C#. The application is a console application targeting .NET 4.7. From that application I want to programmatically check if .NET Core 3.1.300 runtime is installed. If not then I want to install it. How to do that ?
So far I haven't found any API to check the installed .net core runtime.

Comment: how about using the `Registry` ?

Comment: @HMZ How to do that ? Any pointer to start ?

Comment: see here its already been asked : [Github](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/2953)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically get current running version of dotnet core runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49309108/programmatically-get-current-running-version-of-dotnet-core-runtime)

Comment: Also that: [Getting the .NET Core Runtime Version in a Running Application](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2018/Apr/12/Getting-the-NET-Core-Runtime-Version-in-a-Running-Application)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38567353/how-to-determine-if-net-core-is-installed

Comment: @OlivierRogier he's running on .net framework and wants to check the current .net core version.

Comment: @HMZ Thus the title is misleading. So that can help: [How to check that .NET Core is already installed](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/install/how-to-detect-installed-versions)

Answer (score 4):

To save you the trouble you have to query these locations in the registry:

## For x64 versions

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x64\sharedfx\Microsoft.NETCore.App`

## For x86 versions

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x86\sharedfx\Microsoft.NETCore.App`

This may change in the future but from what i've seen and from my machine all the versions are logged in these locations.

## Regarding Linux

from the docs link that Olivier Rogier suggested you can check for these folders:

dotnet executable
/home/user/share/dotnet/dotnet

.NET SDK
/home/user/share/dotnet/sdk/{version}/

.NET Runtime
/home/user/share/dotnet/shared/{runtime-type}/{version}/

Comment: @HMZ Which one is a better option according to you ? Checking the dotnet folder or checking the registry ?

Comment: @Ayan for windows you check the registry and for linux you check for the folders i mentioned above. in windows i would choose the registry over the dotnet folder. its faster and simpler

Answer (score 1):

Yes. From `.Net Core 3` you can use:

```
var netCoreVer = System.Environment.Version; 
var runtimeVer = System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription;
```

Comment: This is useful for examining the _running application's_ underlying framework, but doesn't answer the question as asked.