# .NET CLR / Framework detection at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks, runtime

Is it possible to determine at runtime:

1. Which version of the .NET framework the application is targeting?
2. If the application is targeting a full or client profile of the framework?

I have tried using `Environment.Version` however this produces highly inaccurate results. Equally, I have been unable to find any solutions for determining which profile is being used.

Comment: Interesting question, though I wonder why you would need to do this. After all, when you compile your code, you usually have to target a specific framework & profile...?

Comment: @stakx, I can't say its a case of "needing" to do it. I just want to know if its possible. Say for example I am writing a helper class that will tell you about your application, which OS its running on, which CLR its running on, which framework and profile are being targeted etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way to check .NET Framework version using C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951856/is-there-an-easy-way-to-check-net-framework-version-using-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) Which version of the .NET framework the application is targeting?

A .NET assembly is targeting a specific version of the framework. But as you know you could have an assembly compiled against .NET 2.0 be loaded into the CLR 4.0. At runtime you could know the CLR version being used to host the application with the [Environment.Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.version.aspx) property.

> 2) If the application is targeting a full or client profile of the framework?

The .NET profile is not something that could be determined at runtime. It is only used by Visual Studio to grey out some assemblies in the Add References dialog to prevent you from referencing an assembly that might not be available at runtime. By the way this notion was removed in .NET 4.5.

Comment: Why would Microsoft bother making a client profile then? surely you can set the client profile and then just re-reference those "greyed out" assemblies? Surely it would be better to add functionality to VS that checks to see if an assembly is being used, and remove those that are not?