# Put dotNet Install Package Locally with WPF Program

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a WPF program, a standalone one, copy from "Release" directory. So its a green software without installation.

BUT it requires .net 4.0 installed. So I have "dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe" on the distribution USB disk.

Problem is, when my program run on XP (without .net 4.0), it will say it needs .net 4.0 and ask user if they want to go online to download it even I have a local copy on the disk.

My question is, is there anyway let the program install the .net locally without go online to download.

Comment: Why not include the .Net4.0 installation within the release and then if it is detected that the machine does not have .NET4.0 installed, run the file directly (from the `Application.StartupPath`)?

Comment: The context menu in Solution Explorer will have a 'Publish' option on it.  This will create a full install 'setup.exe' that handles the downloading of the appropriate .NET release

Comment: I just need a standalone application without any install or setup process. I have my reasons

Comment: You could do a silent install i suppose... I doubt you could just make a portable version of the framework or something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem.

Eventually I bit the bullet and created a native C++ bootstrapper (no .NET required to execute) which checked if .NET was installed, and if not, installed it. The bootstrapper then started up the .NET program.

Comment: Ohh, thats nice. Can you email me your program if ok with you. My email eric@ericyin.com thanks

Comment: I sent you the project.

Comment: It would be awesome If you share it to us too :)

Comment: @l0oky: Sorry, but the project is comprised of several files, so sharing it would be really hard.

Answer (score 3):

Standard way of doing this is by creating an installation and setup package which will include your application as well as the .NET framework.

The user will run your setup program and install what is required.

**EDIT :**

If you do not want to use an Installer you could use [Ngen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf.aspx).

> The Native Image Generator (Ngen.exe) is a tool that improves the
> performance of managed applications. Ngen.exe creates native images,
> which are files containing compiled processor-specific machine code,
> and installs them into the native image cache on the local computer.
> The runtime can use native images from the cache instead using the
> just-in-time (JIT) compiler to compile the original assembly.

Unfortunately, you still need the libraries from the .net framework in order to run your program. There's no feature that I know of with the Microsoft .Net framework SDK that allows you to compile all the required files into a single executable

**EDIT 2 :**

After a bit of searching, [this](http://spoon.net/studio) is also worth checking out. It's called Spoon Studio here are It's [features](http://spoon.net/studio). Looks like this is what you were looking for.

> Execute .NET, Java and AIR-based applications with no separate
> installation steps or runtime versioning conflicts. The Spoon virtual
> machine supports all versions of the .NET Framework and Java,
> including .NET 4.0, 4.2, and 4.5.
>
> Deliver virtualized applications in standalone EXEs, on intranets with
> Spoon Server, or on the web with Spoon.net.
>
> Standalone executable generation packages all virtual machine and
> application payload content as a single EXE file that can be deployed
> using any standard file delivery mechanism or existing desktop
> management infrastructure.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to use an installer, you will need to make a launcher instead of running your application from the start.

If you can guarantee .net 2.0 on your system, you could create a 2.0 Winforms project in your solution, check the framework-version like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/951915/1541758), if it is not 4 start the installer *synchronously*, when it finishes running, check the framework version again and finally start your application.

You could start your application without having to have another .exe in there. You would use [Assembly.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky3942xh.aspx) to load your project (which you should compile to a class library then) and call your application startup function.

You will definitely not be able to do this in only one file, though. You need either a native application or .net 2.0 application as launcher.