# Is possible to disable part of program based on .NET version?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

In my current program I'm using some features of .NET 4.0 - specifically the Charting API ( `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting`). I will ship the application, but I'm not sure the client has the .NET 4.0 installed.

Is it possible to add some hooks/event handlers to disable this feature in my program as it's not vital for it's function?

My idea is that when user clicks on `Show Chart` button, message will be shown - "Please install NET 4.0+". I would prefer not to ship 2 versions of my program.

Comment: you have to have .net 4.0 installed to even run it.

Comment: you can't run 4.0 components in an older version of the clr.

Comment: Can you please add this as answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use any 4.0 assembly, you have to have at least .net 4.0 installed, have a process hosted in at least a 4.0 CLR.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the [installed .NET Versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951856/is-there-an-easy-way-to-check-net-framework-version-using-c) of the User and then disabled your feature.
I think this would be the easiest way.

**EDIT:**
See comments, he's right.
Nevertheless if you need to get the versions use this.