# C# only run application if depenancies are installed

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, path, dependencies

So I finished the production of my C# application. However, it is dependent on a quite high level of .NET preferably .NET 4.6. Is there a built in way from visual studio to check if it is installed on a machine and then offer to download and install it or do I have to do path checking in my code?

Comment: Not really build in, but this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951856/is-there-an-easy-way-to-check-the-net-framework-version

Comment: Thanks, I'm found it in the publishing settings but it wants to create setup files, I'd prefer for it to be a single standalone exe though