# Auto upgrading .NET framework

Tags: .net, wpf, frameworks, upgrade, .net-4.6

My distributed App is using .NET 4.6 features.
It's not installed via ClickOnce, but installed manually, for certain reasons.
How can I check if installed .NET is lower version and update it before running app.
My users are not advanced people and I can't send .NET upgrade instructions to them.

Answer (score 1):

Use some of the resources below.

After determining the version you have installed, you will probably want your "code" to deploy .NET using the "Custom Setup (chaining)" method...you can decide if you want it to be silent, show the .NET frameworks' installation UI, or use your own custom one.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942965(v=vs.110).aspx#chaining

### How to Determine Which NET Version Installed

(via `Environment.Version` - not reliable or even recommended way now)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.version(v=vs.110).aspx

(via Registry)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx

### Code and Methods to Detect Version

[Is there an easy way to check the .NET Framework version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951856/is-there-an-easy-way-to-check-the-net-framework-version)

### Deployment of NET Framework

Deployment Guides

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942965(v=vs.110).aspx

(Silent Repair/Install of NET Framework...slightly old)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx