# C# Windows how ro run exe after detect .Net version

Tags: c#, .net, installation, wix

I Have a Three EXE's

EXE1 build with 3.5 net framework

EXE2 build with 4.5 net framework

EXE3 build with 4.6 net framework

I want to run exe after detect which.Net version already installed and according to that start exe

if 3.5 installed
   RUN(EXE1)

if 4.5 installed
   RUN(EXE2)

if 4.6 installed
   RUN(EXE3)

i think about wix setup, iexpress but didnt get any thing so how can we do this ?

or its is possible? if yes then how and if no then so can we do this with the help of third party software?

> so I need a way to run exe as per platform because each platform has
>   their own .Net framework

Comment: Is there a specific reason for this, why not just use 4.6? (or 4.0 if you need XP)

Comment: In this post you can see how to retrive the current installed .net version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951856/is-there-an-easy-way-to-check-the-net-framework-version

Comment: @AlexK.i want to run exe on windows 7,8 and 10 .. but i want to run exe without install prerequisite(.Net framework).. I know how to detect framework from exe but that exe(that detect framework) also need the framework... understand? so i need a way to run exe as per platworm because each platform have there own framwork ...  any question ?

Comment: > so I need a way to run exe as per platform because each platform has
> their own .Net framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is 2 way: using bath file to detect .net version after that run exe for this version
or build a porogram exe depend .net 2 after that this exe decide witch file must run

**Update:**
this samples give you version of .net freamwork are inistaled

**for.net 4 and older**

```
 private static void GetVersionFromRegistry()
{
     // Opens the registry key for the .NET Framework entry.
        using (RegistryKey ndpKey = 
            RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, "").
            OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\"))
        {
            // As an alternative, if you know the computers you will query are running .NET Framework 4.5 
            // or later, you can use:
            // using (RegistryKey ndpKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, 
            // RegistryView.Registry32).OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\"))
        foreach (string versionKeyName in ndpKey.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            if (versionKeyName.StartsWith("v"))
            {

                RegistryKey versionKey = ndpKey.OpenSubKey(versionKeyName);
                string name = (string)versionKey.GetValue("Version", "");
                string sp = versionKey.GetValue("SP", "").ToString();
                string install = versionKey.GetValue("Install", "").ToString();
                if (install == "") //no install info, must be later.
                    Console.WriteLine(versionKeyName + "  " + name);
                else
                {
                    if (sp != "" && install == "1")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(versionKeyName + "  " + name + "  SP" + sp);
                    }

                }
                if (name != "")
                {
                    continue;
                }
                foreach (string subKeyName in versionKey.GetSubKeyNames())
                {
                    RegistryKey subKey = versionKey.OpenSubKey(subKeyName);
                    name = (string)subKey.GetValue("Version", "");
                    if (name != "")
                        sp = subKey.GetValue("SP", "").ToString();
                    install = subKey.GetValue("Install", "").ToString();
                    if (install == "") //no install info, must be later.
                        Console.WriteLine(versionKeyName + "  " + name);
                    else
                    {
                        if (sp != "" && install == "1")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("  " + subKeyName + "  " + name + "  SP" + sp);
                        }
                        else if (install == "1")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("  " + subKeyName + "  " + name);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**and for get .net 4.5 and upper**

```
    using System;
using Microsoft.Win32;

public class GetDotNetVersion
{
   public static void Get45PlusFromRegistry()
   {
      const string subkey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\";
    using (RegistryKey ndpKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32).OpenSubKey(subkey))
      {
        if (ndpKey != null && ndpKey.GetValue("Release") != null) {
            Console.WriteLine(".NET Framework Version: " + CheckFor45PlusVersion((int) ndpKey.GetValue("Release")));
        }
         else {
            Console.WriteLine(".NET Framework Version 4.5 or later is not detected.");
         } 
    }
   }

   // Checking the version using >= will enable forward compatibility.
   private static string CheckFor45PlusVersion(int releaseKey)
   {
      if (releaseKey >= 460798) {
         return "4.7 or later";
      }
      if (releaseKey >= 394802) {
         return "4.6.2";
      }   
      if (releaseKey >= 394254) {
         return "4.6.1";
      }
      if (releaseKey >= 393295) {
         return "4.6";
      }
      if ((releaseKey >= 379893)) {
         return "4.5.2";
      }
      if ((releaseKey >= 378675)) {
         return "4.5.1";
      }
      if ((releaseKey >= 378389)) {
       return "4.5";
      }
    // This code should never execute. A non-null release key should mean
    // that 4.5 or later is installed.
    return "No 4.5 or later version detected";
   }
}   
// Calling the GetDotNetVersion.Get45PlusFromRegistry method produces 
// output like the following:
//       .NET Framework Version: 4.6.1
```

**and by this sample you can run exe file**

```
  using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MyProcessSample
{
    class MyProcess
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Process myProcess = new Process();

            try
            {
                myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                // You can start any process, HelloWorld is a do-nothing example.
                myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\HelloWorld.exe";
                myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                myProcess.Start();
                // This code assumes the process you are starting will terminate itself.
                // Given that is is started without a window so you cannot terminate it
                // on the desktop, it must terminate itself or you can do it programmatically
                // from this application using the Kill method.
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update2:**
by this Update you get latest version of .net at batch File

```
@echo off
 setlocal
@SET INSTALLUTILDIR=
@for /F "tokens=1,2*" %%i in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5" /v "Version"') DO (
    if "%%i"=="Version" (
        SET .NetVer=%%k
    )
)

@for /F "tokens=1,2*" %%i in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full" /v "Version"') DO (
    if "%%i"=="Version" (
        SET .NetVer=%%k
    )
)

    ECHO The most current version of Net in use is %.NetVer%
```

and by this code you can run program but dont forget the bat file must be in folder the exe files are there

```
start myProgram.exe 
exit
```

Comment: Can you provide me with a example?

Comment: i updated my answer by code there is 3 sample try to use them ;-)

Comment: actually i need example of batch file "using bath file to detect .net version after that run exe for this version"  i up your answer

Comment: hey sorry but I am very new in the batch file can you tell me how can i start exe file after check framework

Comment: look at this link http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/write-simple-batch-bat-file/  you just create newt ext and change it type  *.txt  --->  *.bat  and if run it do the codes fast and if you want too see print you need run it by cmd

Answer (score 0):

If you use Windows Installer (such as through wix), you can use the [`MsiNetAssemblySupport` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370325) to condition a custom action that launches your executable. If you use wix specifically, the WixNetfxExtension can be [asked to set other properties](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/check_for_dotnet.html) that may be easier to use. Here is [wix's list of .NET properties](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/wixnetfxextension.html).

However I suspect this is the wrong approach. It should be much easier to write a single .NET executable that targets the lowest framework version you support, and include a .config file<sup>1</sup> with a `supportedRuntime` element that enables it to run on a wider spread of frameworks. (See [How to: Configure an App to Support .NET Framework 4 or 4.5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152935).

Also, depending on what the executable does, you may be better off writing a C++ executable, a C++ DLL (so it can interact with Windows Installer), or even leveraging native Windows Installer functionality instead of custom actions. (If applicable, the last option is ideal.)

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>Note that Windows Installer EXE custom action support for temporary files will only extract a single file to the temp folder, so your .config file would not be found in these configurations. Alternate approaches would be required; various Windows Installer tools have their own approaches for mitigating this problem.</sup>

Comment: I tried this supportedRuntime element  inside the Config file   <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" />
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0.1" />
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/> i build exe on 2.0

Comment: but when i run this on windows 8 x64 bit i got prometed to install .net 3.5 framwork ... on windows 8 x64 . .Net 4.5 already installed why its not run on 4.5 i added supportedRuntime ?