# why Web Forms 4.0 can use a .NET2.0 library

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, webforms, json.net

#### Summary

I am maintaining a ASP.NET Web Forms 4.0 VB.NET project at my company

image from project's web.config
[image]

Because of [Improper Handling of Exceptional Conditions in Newtonsoft.Json](https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-5crp-9r3c-p9vr?fbclid=IwAR3JrH1YTfeaGY1hVU-NDV2pe_NSw8gWCQUD7s-rhdr4ykj0nboggibkNOg)

I need to upgrade the version of Json.NET to 13.0.1 about
`ASP.NET Web Forms 4.0 VB.NET project`

the JsonNet version in Web Forms project's `Bin` folder is .NET2.0 & 8.0.3.(the project I am maintaining)

I found that you can replace the Newtonsoft.Json.dll with new dll(.NET4.0 & 13.0.1) straightly on the old Web Forms 4.0 project on IIS server.
And the original version is .NET2.0 & 8.0.3.

No error result, the porject runs well

I feel the two version are compatible

My problem is why `web forms 4.0` can use a NET2.0 dll?

---

##### Other

this is what I had dowmloaded from [Json.Net github source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/13.0.1).
And this is the all .NET version of the 13.0.1 version Json.NET
**tree structure**
[image: tree map]

Comment: I think it's .NET 4, see [Cleaner HTML Markup with ASP.NET 4 Web Forms - Client IDs (VS 2010 and .NET 4.0 Series)](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series) and [What’s New in ASP.NET 4.0, Part One: Core Engine Features](https://www.codemag.com/article/100133/What%E2%80%99s-New-in-ASP.NET-4.0-Part-One-Core-Engine-Features)

Comment: You can also check the .NET runtime your app is using programmatically as shown in [Is there an easy way to check the .NET Framework version?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/951856).  Based on that you can choose the correct Json.NET DLL.

Comment: @dbc I was confused lol. After figure out the project's target framework that is 4.0, I think that should use the net40 version

Answer (score -1):

.NET framework are [version compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/version-compatibility?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

So .Net framework 2.0 library should work fine on .Net framework 4.0

Also can see [Side-by-Side Execution in the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/side-by-side-execution)

---

##### some basic of Web Forms

According to [What is Web Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/what-is-web-forms)

ASP.NET Web Forms are:

- Based on Microsoft ASP.NET technology, in which code that runs on the server dynamically generates Web page output to the browser or client device.
- Compatible with any browser or mobile device. An ASP.NET Web page automatically renders the correct browser-compliant HTML for features such as styles, layout, and so on.
- Compatible with any language supported by the .NET common language runtime, such as Microsoft Visual Basic and Microsoft Visual C#.
- **Built on the Microsoft .NET Framework. This provides all the benefits of the framework, including a managed environment, type safety, and inheritance.**
- Flexible because you can add user-created and third party controls to them.