# How to know the version of .NET Framework the application is currently running on

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-framework-version

I have an VB.net application where the supportedRuntime is mentioned as `<supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/><supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>` in config file.
According to [Microsoft Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-configure-an-app-to-support-net-framework-4-or-4-5) on computer with version 4 or later versions installed application runs on 4 or later versions.

I have got `Environment.Version` that gives the CLR version but have a warning mentioned as "For the .NET Framework 4.5 and later, we do not recommend using the Version property to detect the version of the runtime" [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.version?view=netframework-4.0)

When I use `Environment.Version` I get "4.0.30319.42000". According to
[microsoft link](https://%5BURL=%22https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed?redirectedfrom=MSDN%22%5D) suggests `For .NET Framework 4.6 and later versions, it has the form 4.0.30319.42000`.

Is there any way to know the exact version of the .NET Framework the application will target on runtime if multiple versions of .NET Framework 4 and above is installed.

Also `RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription` Property gets the name of the .NET installation on which an app is running but requires .NET Framework 4.7.1, 4.7.2, 4.8, 4.8.1.

So I want to know any other method that will work irrespective of the framework version.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951856/is-there-an-easy-way-to-check-the-net-framework-version Btw. The installer should add the _missing_ prerequisites in the target machine.

Comment: It's not clear why you need this information or when you need it. The information can be found in each project's `.csproj` or `.vbproj` file - look at `TargetFrameworkVersion`.