# How to get the installed .Net version (not .Net Framework!)

Tags: c#, .net

I need to check what is the installed .Net version (.Net 6 and higher) but all the info I have found was related to .Net Framework.
I've tried to check in this article but it talks about .Net Core and Framework only.
[Is there an easy way to check the .NET Framework version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951856/is-there-an-easy-way-to-check-the-net-framework-version)

For .Net Framework you can check Registry Key

```
                RegistryKey ndpKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey
                (RegistryHive.LocalMachine, 
                RegistryView.Registry32).OpenSubKey(subkey)
```

I have not found anything similar for .Net versions.

Will appricate your help here!

I'm trying to write a code that checks what is the installed .Net version and I expect to locate a place where I can check for it in order to retrieve the installed version.

Comment: `dotnet --version` - _"Display .NET SDK version in use"_

Comment: You do realise that .NET 6 IS .NET Core, right? 4.8.x is the last version of .NET Framework so there's no need to distinguish any more, so "Core" was dropped from the name. .NET 5 and later are just evolutions of .NET Core. There was no .NET Core 4 because .NET 5 was supposed to be the merging of .NET Framework with .NET Core. Thats from a functionality point of view though. It's was still built on the .NET Core codebase.

Comment: Also, one of the points of .NET Core is that it doesn't have to be installed. It can be, but it can also be distributed with an application in only the parts that are required. There's no guarantee that any version of .NET Core is installed, even if you're running a .NET Core application.

Comment: For runtime: `dotnet --list-runtimes`, for sdks: `dotnet --list-sdks`

Comment: .NET 6+ is .NET *Core* 6+. The name changed from .NET Core to just .NET in v5 for marketing reasons - people were afraid to migrate to a completely new platform, so the platform was renamed. The documentation you're looking for is the .NET Core documentation.

Comment: Why do you need to check the installed version? In .NET Core, you can publish an application as a [self-contained executable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-self-contained) that contains all the runtime and library files it needs to run on a specific platform

Comment: Thanks for all of your inputs.
I need to check what is the installed version of the current app we’re launching as we might need to install a newer version.
So I still need an easy way to find what is the existing version.
I added the code we’ve used for extracting the .Net Framework version.

Comment: "Installed version of the current app" is *entirely* different from "installed version of .NET". Which are you *actually* interested in?

Comment: You are right sorry for misleading.
I'm extracting the .NET type that a certain app is using (Framework or the new .NET)
Then I need to check if it’s installed or not on the current environment
And if it’s installed, I need to check what is the installed version

Comment: I still don't understand the purpose of that, to be honest. I suggest you read https://www.jonskeet.uk/links/stack-hints and edit your question to provide a *lot* more context. (Note that with .NET Core / .NET 5+, a lot of the time applications won't use an "installed" runtime, but one that sits alongside the application itself.)

Comment: @MiritH: You application should be using proper versioning and you should know whether a particular version of your app uses _.NET Framework_ or _.NET_, as well as the version. It wouldn't make any sense to have a version of your app as version _2.0.0_ and have that version using both _.NET Framework v4.8_, and _.NET 6_.